# Difference between em and px in font-size

Tags: css, font-size

I read in [w3school - font-size](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) property that the difference between using `em` and `px` is that when using px IE doesn't support resizing but em does.

I am working on IE7 and it works fine with px and re-size the text when zooming the page.

can any one explain this to me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

px can be resized in IE as well. em is a relativ size to the inherited size by it's parent element and actually has the same meaning as %.

I don't think you can take any advantage by using em instead of px.

Answer (score 1):

I believe old versions of Internet Explorer have this problem, but new versions fixed it. By the way, W3Schools is [often considered a bad resource](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

From memory, IE7 will scale / zoom the whole page, but if you select "Page/Text Size" from the menu to change the text size, that is when px or other absolute units are not scaled whereas relative units (eg: em's) are.

I expect you are doing a zoom rather than a Page/Text Size?

Comment: I am making zoom on the whole page, I just clink( "ctrl" + "+").

Comment: Yes... so that is why. If you go to page/text size, then you will see that fixed px doesn't change in IE.